# Orchard 1.6 Custom Theme Always Shows Date

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to Orchard CMS. I'm currently trying to get my website running with it. To make my Orchard site match my company's brand, I have created a custom theme. That theme is nearly finished. However, I've notice that each page within my site shows a date, and then the content that I've entered into the CMS. I believe the date is the publish date of the content.

To identify what could be the cause, I've done the following:

```
<div style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px">
  test<br />
  @Display(Model.Content)
</div>
```

With this approach, "test" always appears before the date, then the date, then the content that I entered. It's almost as if the date is part of `Model.Content`. I do not want to show the publish date. How can I remove the date from the Model.Content? Or, at least not show it?

Thank you

Comment: The date *is* part of Model.Content, in the sense that Model.Content is a local container, that will itself have zones inside of it (look at the content.cshtml template). The shapes for the different parts of your content items will be dispatched into those zone according to the instructions in the placement.info files. To modify how or if the date is displayed, you can find the relevant template, or act on placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to speculate without seeing more of your code, but I think that the best bet would be that the date is shown as part of your metadata.

If that's the case, you can turn it of in `Placement.info` by adding `<Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-" />` inside it.